# "Rule 30" in the infinite setting

Tags: computability-theory, infinite-combinatorics, cellular-automata

This question tries to get right what went wrong in an [earlier question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/429399/possible-finite-periodicities-of-rule-150-in-the-infinite-setting).

Let $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{Z}$ denote the set of all functions $x:\mathbb{Z}\to \{0,1\}$. Let $+$ denote addition modulo $2$ on $\{0,1\}$ (corresponding to [${\sf XOR}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_gate) in computer science).

Define a function $f:\{0,1\}^\mathbb{Z} \to \{0,1\}^\mathbb{Z}$ by $x \mapsto f(x)$ where $f(x):\mathbb{Z}\to\{0,1\}$ is defined by $$f(x)(i) = x(i-1) \; + \;\max\{x(i), x(i+1)\}\ \text{ for all }i\in \mathbb{Z}.$$ Inductively define $f^{(0)}(x) = x$, and $f^{(n+1)}(x) = f(f^{(n)}(x))$ for all integers $n\geq 0$.

**Question.** For what integers $n>1$ is there $x\in \{0,1\}^\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f^{(n)}(x) = x$ but $f^{(k)}(x) \neq x$ for all integers $k\geq 1$ with $k<n$?

Comment: I think Rule 30 is $f(x)(i)=x(i-1)+\max\{x(i),x(i+1)\}$.

Comment: To others who like me don't want to waste time trying to decipher the formulas, you can find the explicit rule table for Rule 30 for instance [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_30#Rule_set)

Comment: Which rule do you want? The formula describes a CA that's not even surjective and is left-right symmetric, again of completely different nature than Rule 30.

Comment: This formula is not giving rule 30.  It differs on 101 and 011.

Comment: out of curiosity, is there a name for the property of having minimal fixed points of every order?

Comment: If you mean "periodic points", this is sometimes called "omniperiodicity". (At least in the cellular automaton context.)

Comment: I edited and now the formula is correct finally. Thanks @JohanKopra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A partial answer: Table A.1 of https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/236376428.pdf lists the number of preperiodic points with minimal preperiod $q$ and minimal period $p$ with small $q$ and $p$ for various elementary cellular automata. For example, for Rule 30 and for $q=0$, $p=1,2,3,4,5,6$ these cardinalities are $3,0,12,28,45,84$ and in particular there does not exist a configuration with minimal period $2$.

Comment: A few more data points: number of periodic points of period 1: 3; period 2: 3; period 3: 15; period 4: 31; period 5: 48; period 6: 99; period 7: 108; period 8: 119; period 9: 195; period 10: 598. (Non-minimal periods, do inclusion-exclusion to convert.)

Comment: Thanks to Johan for this partial answer - I won't accept it yet, I hope you don't mind. Thanks also to Ville Salo for the additional information!